# Cannot install gazebo_ros_pkgs

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I unistalled with :

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros
```

the gazebo_ros package and its relevant packages (in other words the whole gazebo_ros_pkgs was removed), but now when I type:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros
```

I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros
```

How is it possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245039/cannot-install-gazebo_ros_pkgs/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by updating the apt-get command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I also followed again the steps provided by ros for the repository, but I don't think this actually solved the issue about the installation.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0